Spring JDBC JdbcTemplate inserts ain't committed
I have a problem - I cannot insert data in the table with Spring JDBC.
Don't know is it important, just in case - I have an app that uses Spring/SpringBoot with Spring JPA and other things. The database is Postgresql and everything works fine there.
The problem is, that in the same app I need to connect to another database, which is Firebird. I am trying to insert values to some table in this Firebird database using Spring JDBC and looks like the changes ain't committed.
I've created a simple table for tests:
CREATE TABLE table_master
(
    id       INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name     VARCHAR(200),
    CONSTRAINT t_master_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

And I tried both approaches taken from the Spring documentation, like this:
@SpringBootTest
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
@Slf4j
class JdbcTest {
    private DataSource fbDataSource;

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3055//opt/fb/db/DB.GDB");
        config.setUsername("user");
        config.setPassword("passwd");
        config.setAutoCommit(false);
        fbDataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    private static final String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO table_master(id, name) VALUES(?, ?)";
    private static final String cntQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_master";

    @Test
    public void testFbLoad() throws SQLException {
        JdbcTemplate fbJdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(fbDataSource);
        DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
        def.setPropagationBehavior(DefaultTransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
        def.setIsolationLevel(DefaultTransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED);
        TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(def);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            if (fbJdbcTemplate.update(insertQuery, i, "Row #" + i) == 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Cannot insert row #" + i);
            }
        }
        transactionManager.commit(status);

        Integer cnt = fbJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(cntQuery, Integer.class);
        log.info("Rows in table_master: {}", cnt);
    }


and this:
 @Test
    public void testFbLoad() throws SQLException {
        JdbcTemplate fbJdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(fbDataSource);
        TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
        transactionTemplate.execute(status ->
                {
                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                            if (fbJdbcTemplate.update(insertQuery, i, "Row #" + i) == 0) {
                                throw new RuntimeException("Cannot insert row #" + i);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log.error("Rolling back: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
                        status.setRollbackOnly();
                    }
                    return null;
                }
        );


        Integer cnt = fbJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(cntQuery, Integer.class);
        log.info("Rows in table_master: {}", cnt);
    }

And in both cases I observe that JdbcTemplate#update calls are executed but on completion I see no data in the table and "Rows in table_master: 0" in the log with no errors.
I have no idea what am I doing wrong. Please help, how should I use Spring JDBC for such a tasks?
Update:
Well, I tried @Transactional and it also gives me a strange result:
    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testFbLoad() throws SQLException {
        JdbcTemplate fbJdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(fbDataSource);
        TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
        transactionTemplate.execute(status ->
                {
                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                            if (fbJdbcTemplate.update(insertQuery, i, "Row #" + i) == 0) {
                                throw new RuntimeException("Cannot insert row #" + i);
                            }
                        }
                        status.setRollbackOnly();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log.error("Rolling back: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
                        status.setRollbackOnly();
                    }
                    return null;
                }
        );


        Integer cnt = fbJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(cntQuery, Integer.class);
        log.info("Rows in table_master: {}", cnt);
    }


In this case all inserts made are rolled back, but I observe "Rows in table_master: 100"
Please help. Thank you!
Update 2:
looks like I found the reason. Here's the log:
2024-11-30T04:00:50.693+02:00 DEBUG 15770 --- [    Test worker] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2024-11-30T04:00:50.693+02:00 DEBUG 15770 --- [    Test worker] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT INTO table_master(id, name) VALUES(?, ?)]
2024-11-30T04:00:50.693+02:00 DEBUG 15770 --- [    Test worker] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2024-11-30T04:00:50.701+02:00 DEBUG 15770 --- [    Test worker] o.f.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations   : readStatusVector arg:isc_arg_gds int: 0
2024-11-30T04:00:50.711+02:00 DEBUG 15770 --- [    Test worker] o.f.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations   : readStatusVector arg:isc_arg_gds int: 0
2024-11-30T04:00:50.711+02:00 DEBUG 15770 --- [    Test worker] o.f.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations   : readStatusVector arg:isc_arg_gds int: 0
2024-11-30T04:00:50.724+02:00 DEBUG 15770 --- [    Test worker] o.f.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations   : readStatusVector arg:isc_arg_gds int: 0
2024-11-30T04:00:50.726+02:00 DEBUG 15770 --- [    Test worker] o.f.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations   : readStatusVector arg:isc_arg_gds int: 0
2024-11-30T04:00:50.728+02:00 DEBUG 15770 --- [    Test worker] o.f.jaybird.xca.FBManagedConnection      : End called: Xid[1219176952]
2024-11-30T04:00:50.731+02:00 DEBUG 15770 --- [    Test worker] o.f.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations   : readStatusVector arg:isc_arg_gds int: 0
2024-11-30T04:00:50.731+02:00 DEBUG 15770 --- [    Test worker] o.f.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations   : readStatusVector arg:isc_arg_gds int: 0
2024-11-30T04:00:50.731+02:00 DEBUG 15770 --- [    Test worker] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection   : HikariPool-1 - Executed rollback on connection org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBConnection@5f5fe604 due to dirty commit state on close().
2024-11-30T04:00:50.731+02:00 DEBUG 15770 --- [    Test worker] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction commit
2024-11-30T04:00:50.732+02:00 DEBUG 15770 --- [    Test worker] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1821322830<open>)]
2024-11-30T04:00:50.732+02:00 DEBUG 15770 --- [    Test worker] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : committing
2024-11-30T04:00:50.733+02:00 DEBUG 15770 --- [    Test worker] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(1821322830<open>)] after transaction

So, JdbcTemplate closes connection after update and Hikari rolls it back then. The question is still the same - what am I doing wrong and how to fix it?
Thank you!
Update3:
Just in case I've filed a issue report here, but maybe it's my fault and there's a solution. Please help.

There is 1 transaction so it is all or nothing, you generate an error so everything wil be rolled back. Not sure what else you would expect. Next to that if you have multiple datasources you also would need multiple transaction managers (unless you are using JTA, which I hope you aren't) one for each transactional resource.

I expect either no inserted rows if I rollback the transaction, or 1 inserted row when I commit it.

I would expect nothing as you have disabled auto-commit. The transaction manager you are using is tied to another datasource not the one you create in your test. So as nothing is being committed I would expect nothing in the table and that is exactly what is happening.

I want transaction manager to manage both. As I understand, it is able to do that.

It isn't. Your understanding is wrong. A transaction manager can only manage a single transactional resource in this case the datasource that is bound to JPA and not your own created (which Spring doesn't even know about). So you need an additional transaction manager for this or start using JTA (which I would not suggest doing).

Well, thank you. Do I understand it correctly, that spring is able to handle common transactions with, lets say, db and kafka, but cannot handle transaction for two different datasources? They should have it clearly stated in th docs at least...

Kafka is non transactional so that doesn't make sense. It applies to all transactional resources each one needs a dedicated transaction manager. So if you use JDBC and JMS you need 2 transaction managers one for each, the same for multiple datasources. Transactions are tied to specific underlying resources not resource types. The only exception to this rule is JTA (distributed transactions) which bring along a whole other challenge.

For last 30 years I do know what transactions are and how they work ) Ok, thank you!

Well, got another question - is spring able to manage separate transactions for different datasources? Like, how could I make this datasource managed by spring? As I actually don't need jta, this is a single ds I use in this part of my app

Sure why not if you add another transaction manager for it. Just wrap it in another DataSourceTransactionManager instead of autowiring it in your test and magically your code will work. Which should be something you know if you already know for 30 years how transactions work.

Well, so this is the answer. It would be great if you could write it as such. Thank you

The problem is your test as it doesn't really make sense.

You create a DataSource outside the scope of Spring
You are injecting a PlatformTransactionManager that is tied to a different DataSource.

Due to this there is no dedicated PlatformTransactionManager for your own embedded DataSource. If you would rewrite your test to the following
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
@Slf4j
class JdbcTest {

    private DataSource fbDataSource;
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3055//opt/fb/db/DB.GDB");
        config.setUsername("user");
        config.setPassword("passwd");
        config.setAutoCommit(false);
        fbDataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);

        this.transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(fbDataSource);
    }

    private static final String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO table_master(id, name) VALUES(?, ?)";
    private static final String cntQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_master";

    @Test
    public void testFbLoad() throws SQLException {
        JdbcTemplate fbJdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(fbDataSource);
        DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
        def.setPropagationBehavior(DefaultTransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
        def.setIsolationLevel(DefaultTransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED);
        TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(def);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            if (fbJdbcTemplate.update(insertQuery, i, "Row #" + i) == 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Cannot insert row #" + i);
            }
        }
        transactionManager.commit(status);

        Integer cnt = fbJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(cntQuery, Integer.class);
        log.info("Rows in table_master: {}", cnt);
    }
}

This will work as you now have a PlatformTransactionManager for the specific transactional resource, in this case your DataSource.
If you define an additional DataSource and are not using JTA then you also need an additional transaction manager.
@Configuration
public class MyFirebaseConfig {

  @Bean
  public DataSource firebaseDataSource() { ... }

  @Bean
  public DataSourceTransactionManager firebaseTransactionManager(DataSource firebaseDataSource) {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(firebaseDataSource);
  } 

  // Other beans like JdbcTemplate etc.
}

Now if you have a service that requires this you can specify the name of the transaction manager to use in the @Transactional.
@Service
public class SomeService {

  private final JdbcTemplate jdbc;

  public SomeService(@Qualifier("firebaseJdbcTemplate") JdbcTemplate jdbc) {
    this.jdbc=jdbc;
  }

  @Transactional("firebaseTransactionManager")
  public void foobar() { ... }
}

To inject the specific DataSource or JdbcTemplate you can use an @Qualifier.

I thought creating jdbctemplate from the datasource makes it managed. Got it, thank you!
